# Pinterest style layout iOS storyboards

Tags: ios, layout, xamarin, uicollectionview, pinterest

I want to create a design like so :-

[image]

I am using storyboards and i cannot make this thing work. I have a simple collection view as of now and it works fine except all cells show up twice. Is there a way i can achieve this by not using any library and having random heights for cells?

This is my storyboard :-

[image]

---

**Mycollectioncontroller**

```
public MyCollectionController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
{

}

public override void ViewDidLoad ()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad ();
    data = MakeDataForRecyclerView(pageIndex);
}

public override nint NumberOfSections (UICollectionView collectionView)
{
    return 1;
}

public override nint GetItemsCount(UICollectionView collectionView, nint section)
{
    return data.Length;
}

public override void ItemSelected (UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    var message = string.Format ("You clicked on {0}!", cell.Title);
    new UIAlertView ("Clicked", message, null, "Okay", null).Show ();
}

public override UICollectionViewCell GetCell (UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    cell = (MyCollectionCell) collectionView.DequeueReusableCell ("My_Collection_Cell", indexPath);
    var tag = data[indexPath.Row];
    cell.PopulateData (tag.Title, tag.ThumbnailPath);
    return cell;
}

public override void ItemHighlighted(UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    var cell = collectionView.CellForItem(indexPath);
    cell.ContentView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Yellow;
}

public override void ItemUnhighlighted(UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    var cell = collectionView.CellForItem(indexPath);
    cell.ContentView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
}

public override bool ShouldHighlightItem(UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    return true;
}

private Models.DummyModel[] MakeDataForRecyclerView(int startPosition)
{
    List<Models.DummyModel> listOf4Item = new List<Models.DummyModel>();

    for (int i = startPosition * 4; i < Math.Min((4 * startPosition) + 4, AppDelegate.myList.Count); i++)
    {
        listOf4Item.Add(AppDelegate.myList.ElementAt(i));
    }

    return listOf4Item.ToArray();
}
```

---

**MyCollectionCell**

```
public MyCollectionCell (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
{

}

public void PopulateData(string title, string placeholderURL)
{
    //lblTitle.Text = title;
    placeholderImg.SetImage(url: new NSUrl(placeholderURL),
                            placeholder: UIImage.FromFile("ic_apptitle.png"));
}
```

Comment: Would you show a screenshot of the storyboard? 
If the whole view is a `UICollectionView` and its cells would you show the `UICollectionViewDelegate` methods?

Comment: Why you're returning 2 for number of sections???!! Should be 1. or it will show all cells twice.

Comment: @Ismail Sorry  I noticed that now. I fixed it by changing it to 1. Now I can see one single section, but the heights are still the same

Comment: Where the part of the  code you set the cell sizes?

Comment: @Ismail See my output screenshot. Iam not sure where to set the cell sizes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101761/discussion-between-ismail-and-hello-world).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in here:

```
public override nint NumberOfSections (UICollectionView collectionView)
{
    return 2; // should be 1 not 2
}
```

to set different sizes to your cells you may add this method:

```
public override SizeF GetSizeForItem (UICollectionView collectionView, UICollectionViewLayout layout, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    // return the size you want for the cell at this indexPath
}
```

Comment: I fixed that. But my main concern is about the uneven cells

Comment: Thank you for all the help. Appreciate it.

Comment: Hey could you please help me with removing/reducing the space between cells?

Comment: @helloworld The same way as `GetSizeForItem(` there is two more methods for spaces between rows and cells.  `GetMinimumInteritemSpacingForSection(UICollectionView, UICollectionViewLayout, Int32) : Single` 

    The spacing between items in the rows or columns of a section.

 `GetMinimumLineSpacingForSection(UICollectionView, UICollectionViewLayout, Int32) : Single `The spacing between rows or columns of a section.